# Frequency estimation in binary prediction task

Tags: learning, experimental-psychology, reinforcement-learning

In a binary prediction task, people often match choice probabilities to outcome probabilities (a phenomenon known as *probability matching*).

However, under certain circumstances (eg, existence of a pattern), people perform maximization (always choosing the more probable outcome).

Is there evidence in the literature, that even when people are maximizing, they internally learn the underlying probabilities of outcomes?